# Непонятки с выводом элементов массива

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

```
var barr=["aaa","bbb","zzz"]; 
var ii; 
function myfunc () {
    for(ii = 0; ii <  birzes.length; ii++) {
        $.get("time.php?birza=...",function(data) {
            ar = JSON.parse(data);
        }); 
        document.write(barr[ii]+"..."); 
    }
}
```

---

1. в отладчике пишет что `barr[ii]` - `undefined`.
2. `Unexpected token <`  в строке `ar = JSON.parse(data);`

Вторую проблему решил с помощью `JQuery.parseJSON`

Подскажите, как такое может быть с `barr[ii]`?

Comment: @Sergei Sergeev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: ну так var ii не определена, после вызова функции myfunc () присваивается значение

Comment: спасибо но - если она ii глобальная ?

Comment: переместил var barr=["aaa","bbb","zzz"]; в функцию myfunc. добавил var перед ii в for...- вроде решилось. всем спасибо

Comment: оформите код нормально.

Comment: Unexpected token потому что вы не json передаете, видимо какой-то html тэг прилетел. смотрите в отладчике передаваемые данные.

Comment: переписал так - работает как надо...
var barr=["aaa","bbb","zzz"]; 
for(var ii = 0; ii < birzes.length; ii++)
{
s1="func.php?birza="+birzes[ii];
ab=data.bids; 
$.ajax({
 async: false,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: s1,
  success: function(data){...}});

Answer (score 1):

Ну такое может быть например если birzes.length больше 3, у Вас ведь не видно откуда это берется)

Comment: спасибо. да birzes.length > 2 . но вопрос остался и как его решать следуя логике ?

Answer (score -1):

переписал так - работает как надо...

```
var barr=["aaa","bbb","zzz"]; 
for (var ii = 0; ii < barr.length; ii++) {
    s1="func.php?barr="+barr[ii];
    $.ajax({ 
        async: false,
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        url: s1, success: 
        function(data) {...}
    });
```

немаловажно  вот это - $.ajax({
    async: false,...ожидать данные...

http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript-jquery/thread885633.html

Comment: async false - плохо. очень плохо.